# Inequality and Infinite Sum of A Function

Tags: inequality, summation, infinity

**Part 1**

Have been given the following inequality,

$$\left|\frac 1 {2+a}\right|<1 $$

I am a but confused about how to solve it.

**My Approach**

I have used the following method,
$$\left|\frac 1 {2+a}\right|<1 $$
$$-1<\frac{1}{(2+a)}, \qquad  \frac{1}{(2+a)}<1$$

$$-(2+a)>1, \qquad 1>(2+a)$$

$$(2+a)<-1, \qquad 1>(2+a)$$

$$a<-1-2, \qquad 1-2>a$$

$$a<-3, \qquad -1>a$$

But then I get the following result

$$a<-3, \qquad -1>a$$

Which I am not sure if it is correct or not. I am just unsure about the step that I have done which was when I timed the fraction on the otherside, I turned the inequality because its given in the question that $a$ can be any number so hence it can also be negative, right? So is it right what I have done? Or is it wrong.

**Part 2**
For the given values of a, find the sum of the following,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {(2+a)^n}$$

This one I am a bit lost.

Comment: Why $2-a$ suddenly became $2+a$?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. My apologies and thank you :)

Comment: As a general rule, when $|\frac{1}{x}|<1$, simply write $|x|>1$

Answer (score 1):

For part 2 you have to calculate the sum of a geometric series and it is $\frac 1 {1-b}$ where $b=2+a$ (or $2-a$, I've not clear which is the correct one). In part 2 the start was correct but then $2-a$ turned in $2-a$ and maybe you forgot some $-$.

Answer (score 1):

From $ -1 < \dfrac 1 {2+a}$ you cannot deduce that $-1\cdot(2+a) < 1$ unless you know that $2+a$ is positive, nor can you deduce that $-1\cdot(2+a) > 1$ unless you know that $2+a$ is negative.

But you can do this:
\begin{align}
-1 & < \frac 1 {2+a} \\[10pt]
0 & < \frac 1 {2+a} +1 \\[10pt]
0 & < \frac 1 {2+a} + \frac{2+a}{2+a} \\[10pt]
0 & < \frac{3+a}{2+a}
\end{align}
Then look at three intervals: $(-\infty,-3),\  (-3,-2),\  (-2,+\infty)$.

Comment: Did you change your profile picture? It makes no difference to me I'm just making sure I haven't implanted a false memory. I had you pegged as the "\cdots" and "green profile picture" guy lol.

Comment: @BeautyIsTruth : I've never had a profile picture on m.s.e.  I use \ldots and \cdots and \vdots and \ddots where appropriate, not interchangeably. $\qquad$

Comment: Wow I honestly didn't notice the difference between \cdots and \ldots. Now I just feel silly. I'm still confused about the profile picture thing as well but I guess it doesn't really matter ^_^

Comment: @BeautyIsTruth : \ldots: $1,\ldots,n.$ \cdots: $1,\cdots,n.$ \ldots: $a+\ldots+z.$ \cdots: $a+\cdots+z.$ (I use $\ldots$ in $1,\ldots,n$ and \cdots in $a+\cdots+z. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

your inequality is equivalent to $$1<|2+a|$$ and $$a \ne -2$$ thus we have for $-2<a$ $$1<2+a$$ thus we get $$a<-1$$ and if $$-2>a$$ we get $$1<-(2+a)$$ or $$3<-a$$ which gives $$a<-3$$